# Texto com quebra de linha

Tags: c#, html

Passo algumas infos de produto para um serviço externo de cobrança (site). Na tela desse site, as infos passadas ficam no campo "descrição", dentro de um elemento `h3`, que parece ter 25 espaços com altura flexível.

Eu passo assim:

```
var descricao = "Codigo: " + codigoProduto + Environment.NewLine + "Nome: " + 
nome + Environment.NewLine;

try
        {
            paymentRequest.Items.Add(
             new Item(
                "BASIC " + CodID,
                 descricao,
                 1,
                 valor
             )
         );
```

Na tela aparece tudo junto numa mesma linha desse campo descrição.

Porém, o que se pretende é que fiquem uma info em cada linha, como por exemplo:

```
Código: 1234
Nome: Daniel
```

Dessa forma funciona mas aparece o br na tela.

```
descricao = $"Codigo: {CodID} <br/> Nome: {nome}";
```

Código fonte da pagina que recebe os dados:

```
      <td>
        <h3 title="Codigo: 1983 br / Nome: Daniel">Codigo: 1983 br 
         / Nome: Daniel</h3>
            Quantidade: 1<br />
            Valor do item: R$ 6,00
        </td>
```

Comment: A tag da pergunta já ajuda a identificar de qual linguagem está falando. Não precisa por no título.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outra solução:

```
string retorno = $"<h3>Codigo: {codigoProduto} <br> Nome: {nome} <br> Valor:  {valor} </h3>";
```

Comment: Para o caso em questão a resposta acima foi a que mais se aproximou.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
var NewLineHTML = "<br>" + Environment.NewLine;

var res = $"Codigo: {codigoProduto}" + NewLineHTML +
          $"Nome: {nome}" + NewLineHTML +
          $"Valor: {valor}" ;
```

o que ficaria assim no html, dentro da tag `h3` preexistente:

```
<h3>
Codigo: 789<br>
Nome: CHURRASCO<br>
Valor: 12,34
</h3>
```

Renderizado:
[image: exemplo]

---

Remendo (Patch):
Pelo que vi o sistema está tirando o `<` e `>` e por isto aparece `br` ... 
Talvez você pode tentar hackear isto, fazendo isto:

mude para:

```
var NewLineHTML = "_br_" + Environment.NewLine;
```

e na página adicione este `script`

```
<script>
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/_br_/g, '<br>');
</script>
```

Comment: o site não renderizou conforme. Ficou tudo junto.

Comment: Mesmo com o `<br>` ele não renderizou? Verifique o HTML gerado no browser, talvez o site esteja removendo as tags `<br>`

Comment: o br aparece inclusive na tela.

Comment: Você pode adicionar à pergunta este trecho que está sendo gerado? Seria então algum `CSS` que está influenciando isto?

Comment: Ah, sim, então ele está escapando o `<` e `>`  ou removendo eles?

Comment: Adiciona o print do site à pergunta;

Comment: Não deu. Não quebra a linha ....